# Why does changing the comparison in a HAVING clause from '=' to '<' change the output when there are no matches?

Tags: mysql

In the following query, changing the comparison operator in the HAVING clause from '=' to '<' when the query returns no results changes the output so that there's either 1 row returned (of all NULLs) or no rows returned.

Can someone explain why this behaviour is as demonstrated? I'd ideally like to have the first query return 0 rows, but it would be nice if it could be done without wrapping it in another query to exclude the NULLs.

**Query:**

```
SELECT `templates`.* 
FROM `templates` 
INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`template_id` = `templates`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(items.id) = 0
```

**Results:**

```
NULL,NULL,NULL...
(1 row(s) returned)
```

In comparison to:

**Query:**

```
SELECT `templates`.* 
FROM `templates` 
INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`template_id` = `templates`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(items.id) < 0
```

**Results:**

```
(0 row(s) returned)
```

But also, this variation with `HAVING COUNT(items.id) < 1` returns the row of NULLs:

**Query:**

```
SELECT `templates`.* 
FROM `templates` 
INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`template_id` = `templates`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(items.id) < 1
```

**Results:**

```
NULL,NULL,NULL...
(1 row(s) returned)
```

Comment: Please use the "where"  instead of "having"... we are using "having" with group by.

Comment: `COUNT` cannot ever return something that is less than 0, but returns 0 easily; of course the output is different.

Comment: Your question seems to have been answered correctly.  `EXPLAIN SELECT` on these queries could be enlightening.  The `Extra` column in this output may reveal that `COUNT(...) < 0` is getting optimized away, something along the lines of "Impossible HAVING."  A similar result can be obtained with something like `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE 1 = 0;`  The server doesn't bother to even run the whole query, since the optimizer concludes that no rows could ever match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, count() function never return negative. your condition says `having count(items.id) < 0` which means `having 0 < 0` which is always `false`. But `having count(items.id)=0` can be true means or `count(items.id)<1` can be true means 0=0 or 0<1 are true.

```
mysql> select 1 from test  having count(id)=0;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.29 sec)

mysql> select 1 from test having count(id)<0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```